# A family of difference sets (paper by A. L. Whiteman)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I was reading [A. L. Whiteman - A family of difference sets](http://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1255631810). On page 109, the author generalizes the reduced residue system modulo $v$ where $v=pq$, $p$ and $q$ are primes. At the last paragraph, can someone explain why if $p-1=df$ and $q-1=ef'$ and $(f,f')=1$, if $ff'$ is odd, then $-1 \equiv g^{(d/2)} \pmod v$, and if $ff'$ is even, there does not exist any $s$, $s=0,\dotsc, d-1$, where $d$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ such that $-1 \equiv g^{s}\pmod v$?

Comment: Could you give a reference to the paper?  [MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=Whitman&co4=AND&pg5=TI&s5=difference) has not heard of it.  Without that, it seems impossible to answer your question, which, for example, does not define $g$.

Comment: $g$ is the common primitive root of p and q

Comment: @LSpice it looks like it has DOI 10.1215/ijm/1255631810

Comment: @Mark, ah, it's Whiteman, not Whitman!  Thanks!  Here's [your](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391824/a-family-of-difference-set-paper-by-a-l-whitman#comment999503_391824) DOI link:  [Whiteman - A family of difference sets](http://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1255631810).  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$ is not cyclic, but is generated by $x =(a,1)$ and $y = (1,b)$ where $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$ and $b$ is primitive mod $q$. Whiteman's Lemma 1 shows that $xy$ has order the least common multiple of $p-1$ and $q-1$. Clearly $\langle x, xy\rangle$ is the whole multiplicative group.

In the portion of the paper to which the question refers, Whiteman wants to decide whether $-1 \in \langle xy\rangle$. Equivalently, whether there exists an integer $m$ such that $a^m \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and $b^m \equiv -1 \bmod q$.

Whiteman's choice of notation is standard for working with cyclotomic difference sets, but slightly hard to follow otherwise. Let $e = \gcd(p-1, q-1)$, and suppose that both $\frac{p-1}{e}$ and $\frac{q-1}{e}$ are odd. Taking $m = \frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2e}$, it's easy to see that $a^m = (a^{(q-1)/e})^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and similarly for $b$. So $(xy)^m \equiv -1 \bmod pq$.

On the other hand, if $\frac{p-1}{e}$ is even and $\frac{q-1}{e}$ is odd, the conditions on $a^{m} \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and $b^{m} \equiv -1 \bmod q$ are inconsistent and $-1 \notin \langle xy \rangle$. Whiteman goes on to express $-1$ as a product of generators of the multiplicative group.

Comment: In the paper, we start with the common primitive root $g=xy(mod pq)$. Then how $<x,xy>$ becomes the generating set?

Comment: In the third para, can you elaborate more on the arguments. How $a^m \equiv -1 \mod p $ and how similar argument works for $b$ but in another case we get inconsistency.

Comment: First -- the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ is not cyclic, so doesn't have a primitive root. Compute some examples to convince yourself of this. Second -- in the third paragraph, $m$ must be even to get a solution $\bmod p$ and odd for a solution $\bmod q$, which is impossible. So no power of $xy$ evaluates to $-1 \bmod pq$. I think your confusion here will be resolved by thinking about my first sentence, and computing some explicit examples.

Comment: I tried to look at the case when $pq=35$. The common primitive root for $7$ and $5$ is $3$ and $e=2$, $\frac{5-1}{2}=2$ is even, $\frac{7-1}{2}=3$ is odd. The value of $x$ and $y$ I computed are $8$ and $31$ respectively. From this onward can you elaborate the argument. I'm confused about $a$ and $b$ and the set generated notation.

Comment: I agree that $x \equiv 8 \bmod 35$. And $y \equiv 31 \bmod 35$. Then $xy \equiv 3 \bmod 35$, and this generates a cyclic subgroup of order $12$. But the multiplicative group has order $24$, and the elements which are not powers of $3$ belong to $8\langle 3 \rangle = \{ 8 \cdot 3^j \bmod 35 \}$. You can compute that $8 \cdot 3^9 \equiv -1 \mod 35$.

Comment: So, according to the notations used   $m=6$ but I didn't understand the inconsistency I mean what $a$ and $b$. Because in both the cases irrespective of $\frac{p-1}{e}$ and  $\frac{q-1}{e}$ even or odd, the order of element $xy$ is lcm(p-1,q-1).

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The given value of $m$ solves $(xy)^{m} \equiv -1 \bmod pq$ when both $\frac{p-1}{e}$ and $\frac{q-1}{e}$ are odd. Otherwise, it does not, because there is no solution to the congruence. In that case, you need to multiply by a power of $x$.

Comment: This is exactly what my doubt is. I mean I understand the cases when both are odd or either value is even, can verify by examples but not able to prove it for the general case.

Comment: Sorry - I still don't see what you're trying to say. Whiteman's paper is an elaboration of the cyclotomic construction for difference sets. This is normally applied to a group of prime order. It might help you to understand the base case thoroughly, including the relation between the cyclotomic numbers and expressions of the prime as a sum of squares. Then the material in Whiteman's paper is intricate, but nothing one would not expect. In particular, you should see why Whiteman carries out the constructions he does for $-1$, and why this is only a detail in the main argument.

Comment: There's a Chapter in Marshall Hall's Combinatorial Theory where all this is laid out in detail.